# ModX can't view new context

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm a noob to modx. Today I prepared a transport package using MyComponent on a localhost modx install and transferred it to the packages folder of a virtual host on the same server. Now I have two contexts in my vh manager, the original "web" context and a new one named "foo". How do I delete or disable web and make foo the main context so I can view it on my vhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. I just needed to edit the index.php file in the root folder to initialize the right context:

```
    $modx->initialize('foo');
```

Quick fix but not readily apparent.